# EOF exception using Spring RestTemplate in weblogic container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am getting the following EOF error in our service.
It is a spring boot application deployed as war in weblogic server.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://*****/update: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:633)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:498)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes
 at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:312)
 at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:232)
 at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:554)
 at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:688)
 at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:41)
 at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1545)
 at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:52)
 at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:655)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
 ... 10 more
```

This [blo](http://deepakmodi2006.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-fix-javaioeofexception-response.html)g describes exactly what I am seeing. but I am using RestTemplate which should the default HttpClientFactory and not weblogic. can some one explain why and what fix I should do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am posting the answer since it will help other when faced with same issue.

by explicitly setting `HttpClientFactory` on the restTemplate, I was able to get rid of this error. I thought by default, `RestTemplate` use `HttpClient`. I cannot figure out why I needed to set this. but this helped resolve.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(factory);
    template.setErrorHandler(new RestResponseHandler());
    return template;
    }
```

Before I had

```
   @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    return new RestTemplate();
    }
```